# Openssl decrypt from encrypted text from command issue

Tags: linux, encryption, openssl, cryptography

I am using following command to decrypt an base64 string.

```
openssl enc -in ciphertext -out binarytext -d -a

openssl rsautl -decrypt -in binarytext -out plaintext -inkey private.pem
```

I am facing an issue when my cypher text has character /  linux consider it as directory separator. How to fix this issue?

A sample cipher text as:

> MpTF1+cqa23PdxQ6EoG9E77jfRJGYjORc4omawTg/g8jtUDZNNEeEr3waadTSLjQAfmJO94fpaA145yanoU9khrzCd/nAGIIAVwMC67UnsX+XY6dOEZMo41Z0dU1n42rUtkdXgldHXR1SQXaeDyjRnMj/mMMreNdykl8b4vNVPk=
>
> The error which am getting as
>
> ptpll081:Key admin$ openssl rsautl -decrypt -in
>   MpTF1+cqa23PdxQ6EoG9E77jfRJGYjORc4omawTg/g8jtUDZNNEeEr3waadTSLjQAfmJO94fpaA145yanoU9khrzCd/nAGIIAVwMC67UnsX+XY6dOEZMo41Z0dU1n42rUtkdXgldHXR1SQXaeDyjRnMj/mMMreNdykl8b4vNVPk=
>   -out plaintext -inkey PrivateKey.pem Error Reading Input File 22313:error:02001002:System library:fopen:No such file or
>   directory:/SourceCache/OpenSSL098/OpenSSL098-44/src/crypto/bio/bss_file.c:126:fopen('MpTF1+cqa23PdxQ6EoG9E77jfRJGYjORc4omawTg/g8jtUDZNNEeEr3waadTSLjQAfmJO94fpaA145yanoU9khrzCd/nAGIIAVwMC67UnsX+XY6dOEZMo41Z0dU1n42rUtkdXgldHXR1SQXaeDyjRnMj/mMMreNdykl8b4vNVPk=','rb')
>   22313:error:2006D080:BIO routines:BIO_new_file:no such
>   file:/SourceCache/OpenSSL098/OpenSSL098-44/src/crypto/bio/bss_file.c:129:

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

`openssl rsautl -decrypt -in binarytext -out myfile.txt -inkey private.pem`

The important bit here is `-out myfile.txt`

Answer (score 0):

`-in` expects a filename and you're passing the encoded cypher text.

Put the cypher text into a file `input`:

```
MpTF1+cqa23PdxQ6EoG9E77jfRJGYjORc4omawTg/g8jtUDZNNEeEr3waadTSLjQAfmJO94fpaA145yanoU9khrzCd/nAGIIAVwMC67UnsX+XY6dOEZMo41Z0dU1n42rUtkdXgldHXR1SQXaeDyjRnMj/mMMreNdykl8b4vNVPk=
```

and then try:

`openssl rsautl -decrypt -in input -out plaintext -inkey private.pem`